# Open product in popup Prestashop

Tags: popup, prestashop, product

On my prestashop website, when a user click on a product, I want to display this product in popup (with all informations, not just the preview) instead of redirect to the product page.

Is it possible ? Do you know a module or code to do this ?

Thank You !

EDIT : Maybe it's more simple to open it as overview, but how can I do to open the product as overview even if the user clicks elsewhere on the product?

Comment: We have not seen any module for this requirement but it can be achieved through a custom module.

If you are interested in custom module development, we can work for your and help you in adding this feature to your store.

We are a leading developer on PrestaShop and have also earned SuperHero badge. You can check our modules at following link:

http://addons.prestashop.com/en/2_community-developer?contributor=38002

Answer (score 0):

Yes the simplest is to open it as an overview, and in the tpl of your product sheet displayed the information you want in addition that is hidden when the variable 'content = 1'

Regards

Comment: Yes when I open it as overview (with "overview" button) it's exactly what I want. But how can I do to open it as overview even if the user clicks elsewhere on the product ?